# Set Custom option value from cart to product view page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

Set custom option value from cart to product view page in magento 2. i am using on add to cart event checkout_cart_product_add_before and set the option code add_option with option (is_available with yes) but on edit time and update the cart time custom option removed